# AngularJS - select with zero(0) value

Tags: angularjs, select

Select options are:

```
`[
 {StatusID: 0, StatusDesc: "New"}, 
 {StatusID: 10, StatusDesc: "Enabled"}, 
 {StatusID: 30, StatusDesc: "InProgess"},
 {StatusID: 70, StatusDesc: "Done"}
];`
```

In order to display all values I have added option "all" with value ""

```
<select id="StatusID" name="statusID" ng-model="search.StatusID" ng-options="Status.StatusID as Status.StatusDesc for Status in StatusList">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Problem is that on selecting **NEW** with value **0** it display all values while selecting **ALL** it displays nothing.

you can find sample code [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nmusmani/tun3x7f5/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding **statusID** as undefined for **All**

```
[
 {StatusID: undefined, StatusDesc: "All"}, 
 {StatusID: 0, StatusDesc: "New"}, 
 {StatusID: 10, StatusDesc: "Enabled"}, 
 {StatusID: 30, StatusDesc: "InProgess"},
 {StatusID: 70, StatusDesc: "Done"}
 ];
```

Used custom filter

```
$scope.statusFilter = function (item) {
    return $scope.currentStatus === undefined || item.StatusID === $scope.currentStatus
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmusmani/tun3x7f5/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes..

> 1. In your itemslist json, status ids are in string, convert them to numbers.
> 2. You have to say to Angular that you want a strict comparaison. That's easy to do with Angular 1.1.5, because the filter filter has now a third parameter, comparator, where true is a very useful shorthand.

E.g.

```
     <tr ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter:search:true">
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gwnfkxmc/1/

Comment: This does not work; same behaviour. Also I don't want to add **true** param because in real page I have more than one filters. Also, if we have to filter on numbers why should be consider for strict comparison? Updated fiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/nmusmani/gwnfkxmc/5/